# Creating polygon based on view extent in QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, qgis-1

I am looking for a very simple thing. I want to create a polygon based on the current view extent of my project.

In fact I want to:

1. open google satellite layers
2. zoom to my area of interest
3. create a polygon based on the 'view extent'

of course, the GE layer is not important, it should work with any view.view

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like spatial bookmarks - maybe that's also an option.

But given that you have a current polygon layer in the same CRS as the project, you can do this in the python console to add a new feature with the current extent:

```py
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromRect(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().extent()))
l = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
l.startEditing()
l.addFeature(f)
l.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the optimal answer (sorry @Jef, I started digging into the Python console, and will continue, but this one was quicker).

The [QMarxan plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Qmarxan/) allows for creating a grid from the view extent.

Comment: Mind that: **This plugin is deprecated!**

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 3.10 introduced 2 new tools (or maybe in earlier versions). With it, you can convert layer features to bookmarks or vice versa:

[Convert layer to spatial bookmarks](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#convert-layer-to-spatial-bookmarks)

[Convert spatial bookmarks to layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#convert-spatial-bookmarks-to-layer)

Answer (score 1):

I had this need in QGIS 3x and the following workflow allowed me to quickly create the polygons.

In the map layout I got the map to the scale and extent required and checked the extent values in item properties for the frame.
[image]

I put these into a Google Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DIkh3neqY_aF0jLjv8myjzG16ncx92DyobBSH22scdU/edit?usp=sharing

I then imported them into QGIS as Polygon WKT
[image]

This gave me the polygons I needed for an atlas.