# Creating spatial bookmarks from existing layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, bookmarks

I have a layer with counties. I would like to import the bounding box of each county as a spatial bookmark and name it accordingly. Is this possible?

Comment: The modern version of QGIS (3.10) has the following processing tools: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360052/35561

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add details to the bookmarks such as the names or the project names then I think the only method is to access the **SQLite database** which stores these bookmarks. Using this [great link](https://www.gislounge.com/map-bookmarks-qgis-python-programming-cookbook/) as a guide, you could try running the following where you can define the field name, project name and the CRS:

```
import sqlite3
layer = iface.activeLayer()

dbPath = QgsApplication.qgisUserDbFilePath()
# if QGIS v3.14 or later, use following line instead:
# dbPath = QgsApplication.qgisUserDatabaseFilePath()

db = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
cursor = db.cursor()

# Define the following information
fieldName = 'Name'
projectName = 'Scotland'
SRID = '27700'

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    rect = feat.geometry().boundingBox()
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tbl_bookmarks(bookmark_id, name, project_name,xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax,projection_srid)
        VALUES(NULL, '""" + feat[fieldName] + """', '""" + projectName + """', """ + 
        '%f,%f,%f,%f'%(rect.xMinimum(),rect.yMinimum(),rect.xMaximum(),rect.yMaximum()) + """, """ + 
        SRID + """)""")

db.commit()
```

---

Example:

[image: Scotland bookmarks]

---

*Notes:*

*1. The bookmarks panel is not immediately updated, you will need to add a new bookmark to see the panel refreshed.*

*2. I had an issue with the Projection CRS. My layer's CRS was set at `EPSG:27700` but setting the projection to the same CRS resulted in a transformation error. I had to set the projection to `EPSG:4326` to rectify it (I also had OTF disabled).*

Comment: Great. That works already! Only one detail is missing: The bookmarks do not have a name yet.

Comment: @coding_bird - Yeah, I don't think there is a direct method using the API. You may have to access the SQLite database (which QGIS stores the bookmarks in) and add it from there (as described [in this link](https://www.gislounge.com/map-bookmarks-qgis-python-programming-cookbook/)). I'm guessing you would want to name them after the name of each county (i.e. there's a field in your layer containing the names)?

Comment: @coding_bird - Edited my post to include a possible method :)

Comment: Thanks. Very good :-D I removed the first part of your answer, because the "new" part explains everthing much better. I hope you agree.
By the way: This would be a good idea for a QGIS plugin, right? :-)

Comment: @coding_bird - Most welcome! And yes, I also agree with the edit so thanks for that.. I don't think there is an existing plugin which does this (or atleast I couldn't find one) so yeah, I suppose it would be a good idea to make it into a plugin :)

Comment: As of v3.14 (possibly earlier) get the path by running dbPath = QgsApplication.qgisUserDatabaseFilePath()